# multiprocessing MemoryError

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

```
phrases = getPhrases(start_phrase_txt)

pool = Pool(processes=3, maxtasksperchild=1000)

for i in range(0, len(phrases)):
    pool.apply_async(checkPhrase, args=(phrases[i], phrases[i+1:], i, len(phrases),)).ready()

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

phrases - определённые строки из текстовика

checkPhrase - функция, открывающая хромдрайвер (headless) и выполняющая в нём определённые действия. Она обёрнута в блок try/except/finally, в конце которого идёт

```
driver.close()
driver.quit()
return
```

Однако при, например, i=30 возникает ошибка MemoryError.
Как я понимаю, из-за того, что потоки или хромдрайвер не закрываются. Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте блок `finally`, в котором вы закроете драйвер и удалите все его процессы:

```
def checkPhrase(phrase, phrases, i, total):
    try:
        # do some actions
    except Exception as e:
        # handle exception
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        del driver
```